# Photoshop Actions Panel Stop Without Message

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting, actions

I can insert a stop action using the Actions Panel dropdown > "Insert Stop" command. During playback, a popup is displayed with an optional message and a "stop" button. How do I stop an action without showing this popup? Dismissing it is a useless step in my workflow... I want a single action so I can press ctrl-F1 to start it, do manual work, and then press ctrl-F1 to complete it. I don't want to split the action into to multiple parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stop command actually works exactly as you want it to, the only part that doesn't is the actions function key. Assigning a function key to an action plays that action from it's beginning. If you hit the 'play' button on the action panel instead, it would work as you expect.

As a workaround you can assign a shortcut key to the **Action → Play** command. The 'play' command will continue play from whatever is selected in the action panel, which will be where your action stopped. You can, for example, set <kbd>F1</kbd> as the shortcut to your action and <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to play (which will continue your action).

To remove the popup altogether all you need to do is toggle the dialog checkbox next to the 'stop' in the action panel.